# How To Send And Receive Value From Class in C#

Tags: c#, class, oop

I have 2 classes, first **Connector** class

```
public class Connector
{
    private SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection();

    public ErrorProvider ConnectTo(string serverID, string databaseName)
    {
        ErrorProvider errorProv = new ErrorProvider();
        const string defineString = "Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=True;Asynchronous Processing=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";

        try
        {
            if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Open && sqlCon.ConnectionString == string.Format(defineString, serverID, databaseName))
            {
                errorProv.ConnectionStatus = ConnectionStat.Success;
            }
            sqlCon.ConnectionString = string.Format(defineString, serverID, databaseName);
            sqlCon.Open();
            sqlCon.Close();
            errorProv.ConnectionStatus = ConnectionStat.Success;

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            errorProv.ConnectionStatus = ConnectionStat.Fail;
            errorProv.ErrorMessage = ex;
        }
        return errorProv;
    }
}
```

Now I Want to send value to other class call **ErrorProvider**

```
public class ErrorProvider
{    
    public ConnectionStat ConnectionStatus { get; set; }
    public SqlException ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public ConnectionDetils ConnectionDet;
}

public enum ConnectionStat
{
    Success,
    Fail
}

public class ConnectionDetils
{
    public string ServerID { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

and when i try to use it in this code it return by nothing

```
OT.ConnectTo("(local)", "TestOTLab").ErrorMessage.ToString
OT.ConnectTo("(local)", "TestOTLab").ConnectionStatus.ToString
```

i want it to return by error value, connection status, DatabaseName, ServerID and Username.
how could i do this

Comment: Shouldn't ToString() have brackets?

Comment: If the connection succeeds, then `ErrorMessage` will be null, so your call to `.ToString` will throw an exception.

Comment: I updated your variables to be lowerCase so that stackoverflow colors them black and it's easier to read.  I also removed the namespace details since that didn't add any value to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Line `public ConnectionDetils ConnectionDet;` defines a field in the `ErrorProvider` class. You can set and read this field as well as `ErrorMessage` field.

```
ErrorProv.ConnectionStatus = Error.ErrorProvider.ConnectionStat.Success;
ErrorProv.ErrorMessage = "";   // Don't forget this field in 'success' scenario
var details = new Error.ConnectionDetils();
details.ServerID = ServerID;
details. ...the rest of data ...
ErrorProv.ConnectionDet = details;
```

And to read it

```
var status = OT.ConnectTo("(local)", "TestOTLab");
Console.WriteLine(status.details.ServerID); ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the code out in Visual Studio but isn't it just a case of adding the following?

```
var errorProvider = OT.ConnectTo("(local)", "TestOTLab");
if (errorProvider != null)
{
   var errorMessage = errorProvider.ErrorMessage;
   var connectionStatus = errorProvider.ConnectionStat;
   var connectionDetails = errorProvider.ConnectionDetails;

   if (connectionDetails != null)
   {
       var serverID = connectionDetails.ServerID;
       \\insert other variables here...
   }
}
```

Because ErrorMessage is of type SqlException you'll need to pick which property you want to display e.g. message property.

Answer (score 0):

I see the following problems with your code:

```
OT.ConnectTo("(local)", "TestOTLab").ErrorMessage.ToString
OT.ConnectTo("(local)", "TestOTLab").ConnectionStatus.ToString
```

1. You are missing () in your calls to ToString
2. You are causing two connections to the DB because you are calling
   the ConnectTo method twice
3. If the connection succeded you are trying to access the ToString()
   method on a null object.

Try this:

```
    var connector = OT.ConnectTo("(local)", "TestOTLab");
    Console.WriteLine(connector.ConnectionStatus.ToString());
    if (connector.ConnectionStatus == ConnectionStat.Fail)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(connector.ErrorMessage.ToString());
    }
```